# How to transform a list of strings into a list of sentences?

Tags: python, string, split

I am trying to convert a list of strings (block of text) to lowercase and transform the text into a list of sentences, where a sentence is a string delimited by the full stop symbol. For example:

```
['This is some text',
 'that I have. But it',
 'is formatted like this.']
```

I want to make it one string per sentence (and all lowercase). At the present I have this below:

```
def make_sentences(text):

    newstring = ''
    for string in text:       
        newstring += str(string.lower()) + ' '
    newstring = newstring.split('.')

    return newstring
```

This does the job but now some words run over two lines (see below). Is there a better way of approaching this problem to prevent that happening?

```
['my current output lo
 oks like this.']
```

Many thanks

Comment: How do 'some words run over two lines'?

Comment: Your posted text is not valid Python: the three quotation marks in the middle input "string" are invalid as given.  Also,  your output shows no particular problem.  There are no words running over two lines in either the input or output.

Comment: @usr2564301 please see the updated question

Comment: Now you have to add what that looks in your *input*. Your sample text does not have that problem.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using the builtin `.join()` method then `.split()`ing it by `'. '`:

```
def make_sentences(text):
    return ' '.join(text).lower().split('. ')
```

Example output:

```
sample = [
    'This is some text',
    'that I have. But it',
    'is formatted like this.'
]
make_sentences(sample)

>>>['This is some text that I have.', 'But it is formatted like this.']
```

**PS**

I also noticed while writing this but failed to point it out. You have an extra quote before But in your strings

Comment: That is what I get too. OP seems to have another problem.

Comment: I'll +1 if you add the lowercase and fix the typo

Comment: @Lonewoolf are you sure they are true periods?

Comment: Haha pretend that didn’t happen been a long day.

Comment: @Jaba your solution still leaves me with the issue of words being printed over 2 lines. Please see the updated example. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the original strings don’t have any newlines in them? If so then might be worth it to either remove them manually *if possible* or use: `.replace('\n', '')` right after or before the `.lower()`. This will remove any newlines so each sentence is just *hypothetically* words, spaces, or periods.